# Word 2010 automation: why does my application crash whereas excel displays an error 462

Tags: c++, vba, automation, ms-word, com

I'm using C++ for Microsoft Word 2010 automation. When the user closes the application and my programm wants to use the previously obtained IDispatch interface, the programm crashes (unhandled exception). Simular VBA code in Excel gives an "Error 462: The remote server does not exist" error. How can I detect that the application has been closed by the user in a way Excel does.

```
#ifdef  __NO_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS__
#include        "generic/platformdefs.h"
#endif

#include    "test_word.h"

/*
 *  Include the right atlbase.h (depends on the compiler)
 */
#include    "compat/which_atlbase.h"

static  OLECHAR FAR *VISIBLE =
{
     OLESTR( "Visible" )    
} ;

static  OLECHAR FAR *QUIT =
{
     OLESTR( "quit" )   
} ;

static void
VarSetBool( VARIANT *v , BOOL value )
{
    V_VT( v ) = VT_BOOL ;
    V_BOOL( v ) = value ? VARIANT_TRUE : VARIANT_FALSE ;
}

static void
DispatchPropertyPut
(
    CComPtr<IDispatch>  dispatch    ,
    OLECHAR FAR     *property   ,
    VARIANT         *value  
)
{
    HRESULT     status      ;
    DISPID      dispid      ,
            propertyput ;
    DISPPARAMS  parameters  ;
    UINT        n_argument_error;
    VARIANT     result      ;

    /*
     *  Get the dispatch id of the method and arguments to invoke
     */
    status = dispatch->GetIDsOfNames( IID_NULL , 
                      &property , 
                      1 ,
                      LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT , 
                      &dispid ) ;

    if( !SUCCEEDED( status ) )
    {
        throw( 1 ) ;
    }

    /*
     *  Initialize result
     */
    VariantInit( &result ) ;

    /*
     *  need to be able to take the address of this
     */
    propertyput = DISPID_PROPERTYPUT ;

    /*
     *  Setup the parameters
     */
    parameters.cNamedArgs = 1 ;
    parameters.rgdispidNamedArgs = &propertyput ;
    parameters.cArgs = 1 ;
    parameters.rgvarg = value ;

    /*
     *  Get the object
     */
    status = dispatch->Invoke( dispid ,  
                   IID_NULL,              
                   LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,                
                   DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT ,
                   &parameters ,
                   &result ,
                   0,  
                   &n_argument_error ) ;

    /*
     *  Cleanup result if any
     */
    VariantClear( &result ) ;

    /*
     *  Success ?
     */
    if( !SUCCEEDED( status ) )
    {
        throw( 2 ) ;
    }
}

static void
DispatchInvoke
(
    CComPtr<IDispatch>  dispatch    ,
    OLECHAR FAR     *method
)
{
    DISPID      dispid      ;
    HRESULT     status      ;
    DISPPARAMS  parameters  ;

    status = dispatch->GetIDsOfNames( IID_NULL , 
                      &method , 
                      1 ,
                      LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT , 
                      &dispid ) ;

    if( !SUCCEEDED( status ) )
    {
        throw( 3 ) ;
    }

    parameters.cNamedArgs = 0 ;
    parameters.rgdispidNamedArgs = 0 ;
    parameters.cArgs = 0 ;
    parameters.rgvarg = 0 ;

    status = dispatch->Invoke( dispid ,  
                   IID_NULL,              
                   LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,                
                   DISPATCH_METHOD ,
                   &parameters ,
                   0 ,
                   0 ,  
                   0 ) ;

    if( !SUCCEEDED( status ) )
    {
        throw( 4 ) ;
    }
}

void
test_word( int argc , char *argv[] , void *data )
{
    CComPtr<IDispatch>  word        ;
    VARIANT         v       ;
    HRESULT         hr      ;

    OleInitialize( NULL ) ;

    try
    {
        /*
         *  The metrowerks compiler doesn't handle __uuidof() 
         */
#       ifdef __MWERKS__

        hr = word.CoCreateInstance( OLESTR( "Word.Application" ) ,
                        IID_IDispatch , 
                        0 , 
                        CLSCTX_SERVER ) ;

#       else

        hr = word.CoCreateInstance( OLESTR( "Word.Application" ) , 
                        0 , 
                        CLSCTX_SERVER ) ;

#       endif

        if( !SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
        {
            throw( 6 ) ;
        }

        VariantInit( &v ) ;

        VarSetBool( &v , TRUE ) ;

        DispatchPropertyPut( word , VISIBLE , &v ) ;

        DispatchInvoke( word , QUIT ) ;

        VarSetBool( &v , FALSE ) ;

        /*
         *  This will crash the application
         */
        DispatchPropertyPut( word , VISIBLE , &v ) ;
    }
    catch( int where )
    {
        fprintf( stderr , "Exception caught %d\n" , where ) ;
    }

    word.Release() ;

    OleUninitialize() ;
}
```

The excel vba macro looks like this:

```
Sub test_word()

    Dim word As Object

    Set word = CreateObject("word.application")

    word.Visible = True

    word.quit()

    '
    '   Quit the word application before the next statement
    '   and you will get Error 462: The remote server does not exist
    '
    word.Visible = False

    Set word = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @JesperJuhl The comment about the version is irrelevant to the question. The COM interface hasn't changed in the last ten years.

Comment: In the top code in C++, why are you calling word.Release() after OleUnititialize() ? It should be before. You should release all COM pointers before uninitializing COM/OLE.

Comment: @Joseph Willcoxson You're right of course but that doesn't solve the problem of crashing at the given location

Comment: `throw ;` does not make sense.  The program aborts to remind you that the code is illegal, there is no active exception that can be rethrown.  `catch(...)` is also a very bad practice, focusing on proper error reporting is important to get ahead.

Comment: I found out that word is the problem. If I just start word then quit it, the final release on the com object crashes the application. When I do the same with outlook or publisher, everything goes well.

Comment: @HansPassant I've adapted the code

Comment: whoa...  `__MWERKS__`

Comment: @RamblinRose Yep - been using the Codewarrior IDE for more than 20 years (current version since 2000). Thanks to their plugin design, I created plugins to support the Microsoft and GNU toolchains.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment, but comments are limited...it might work as a solution...

Well, generally you wouldn't do what you're doing. You must be setting a breakpoint before the second property put and at that point manually closing Word. Generally, you would capture events from Word and then when Word closed, you would receive notification and then know not to use your interface pointer any more. To protect against not catching events, I might suggest first creating the application to get an IUnknown pointer first. Then when you want to make a call to IDispatch, query for the IDispatch and then make the call, and then release the IDispatch.

When you first create with an IUnknown, it will create an in process handler IUnknown for you. On the first call to query for IDispatch, it will at that point actually start up Word. On subsequent calls to QI for IDispatch and then make the call, the handler may be smart enough to just gracefully fail if Word has been shut down--or it may not. But, I would start there...if you don't want to catch events.

The real proper way to get events from Word and look for the Closing or Closed events.

Wow... just looked at Word events. Looks like there is a Quit event but not a Closing or BeforeClosing event or anything like that. So, you'd want to catch the Quit event. After that, set a flag or release your IDispatch interface and never use it again.

Comment: I found out that word is the problem. If I just start word then quit it, the final release on the com object crashes the application. When I do the same with outlook or publisher, everything goes well.

Comment: The actual question for me is, why can the VBA in for instance Excel know the server is no longer available and might application crashes. Is there a way to handle it like vba is handling it (COM exception 0x800706BA)?

Comment: have you got an example (hopefully C/C++ without MFC) how to get the events from word. I tried to getting events from the open Document (IDocumentEvents) but never received a single one. I know about IConnectionPointFactory and IConnectionPoint.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  Is Word 2010 all patched up? I ran the following against Word 2016 (what I have installed). It's also using Visual Studio 2017 but should compile on any Visual C++ in the last 10 years:

```
#include <comdef.h>
#include <atlbase.h>

class COleInitialize
{
    public:
    COleInitialize()
    {
        OleInitialize(NULL);
    }
    ~COleInitialize()
    {
        OleUninitialize();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    COleInitialize _oleinit;

    IUnknownPtr lpUnk;

    lpUnk.CreateInstance(L"Word.Application");

    CComDispatchDriver disp(lpUnk);
    disp.PutPropertyByName(L"Visible", &_variant_t(VARIANT_TRUE));

    MessageBox(NULL, "Close Word", "Prompt", MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```